# Arduino returning more responses than queries have been sent

Tags: bash, serial-port, arduino, stty

I have a problem when using Arduino to post data to Pachube. The Arduino is configured to return JSON data for the temperature when you send a 't' and return JSON data for the light level when you send an 'l'. This works perfectly through the Arduino Serial Monitor. I then created two bash scripts. One regularly sends the 't' and 'l' commands to Arduino and waits 10 seconds in between each request.

```
while true; do
    echo -n t > /dev/ttyACM0
    echo "$(date): Queried Arduino for temperature."
    sleep 10
    echo -n l > /dev/ttyACM0
    echo "$(date): Queried Arduino for light."
    sleep 10
done
```

This works fine. I get an echo message every 10 seconds. The other script reads the generated JSON from serial port (I basically copied it from some Web page).

```
ARDUINO_PORT=/dev/ttyACM0
ARDUINO_SPEED=9600
API_KEY='MY_PACHUBE_KEY'
FEED_ID='MY_FEED_ID'

# Set speed for usb
stty -F $ARDUINO_PORT ispeed $ARDUINO_SPEED ospeed $ARDUINO_SPEED raw
exec 6<$ARDUINO_PORT

# Read data from Arduino
while read -u 6 f ;do
    # Remove trailing carriage return character added
    # by println to satisfy stupid MS-DOS Computers
    f=${f:0:${#f} - 1}

    curl --request PUT --header "X-PachubeApiKey: $API_KEY" --data-binary "{ \"version\":\"1.0.0\", \"datastreams\":[ $f ] }" "http://api.pachube.com/v2/feeds/MY_FEED_ID"
    echo "$(date) $f was read."
done
```

Unfortunately, this script goes crazy with echo messages telling me several times per 10 seconds that it posted data to Pachube although it should only do it every 10 seconds (whenever the first script told Arduino to create a JSON message). I thought it might be an issue with buffered messages on the Arduino but even when switching it off and on again the problem remains. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am completely unfamiliar with Arduino and a handful of other things you're doing here but here are a few general things I see:

- Bash is almost entirely incapable of handling binary data reliably. There is no way to store a NUL byte in a Bash string. Looks like you're trying to pull some trickery to make arbitrary data readable - hopefully you're sending nothing but character data into `read`, otherwise this isn't likely going to work.
- `read` reads newline-delimited input (or the given value of `-d` if your bash is new enough). I don't know the format the while loop is reading, but it has to be a newline delimited string of characters.
- Use `read -r` unless you want escape sequences interpreted. (You almost always want `-r` with `read`.)
- Unconditionally stripping a character off the end of each string isn't the greatest. I'd use: `f=${f%+($'\r')}`, which removes 1 or more adjacent `\r`'s from the end of f. Remember to `shopt -s extglob` at the top of your script if this isn't the default.
- This shouldn't be actually causing an issue, but I prefer not using `exec` unless it's really required - which it isn't here. Just put `done <$ARDUINO_PORT` to terminate the `while` loop and remove the `-u 6` argument from `read` (unless something inside the loop is specifically reading from stdin and can't conflict, which doesn't appear to be the case). The open FD will automatically close when exiting the loop.
- Don't create your own all-caps variable names in scripts because they are reserved and can conflict with variables from the environment. Use at least one lower-case letter. This of course doesn't apply if those variables are set by something in your system and you're only using or modifying them.

Comment: Thanks for your numerous hints. I will see if they produce some change in behavior and give some feedback then.

Comment: Hi ormaaj. Unfortunately none of your proposals helped. Thanks anyway. Other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with `set -x` to determine what's triggering the loop to advance? Is it just "several" times and then waiting to receive something or just running in a tight loop not waiting for anything?

Comment: set -x does not help either. I think it's just "several times". Hence it still seems there is a full buffer somewhere.